# How to count (distinctly) the amount of clients who have stock > 0

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need help with Power BI.

I need to create a meausure to incorporate in the TABLE visualization (which varies according to the filter from the table DATE) so that I can count (distinctivly) the amount of clients who have stock > 0.
If the sum in the stock column is more than 1, it should count it as just one:
example: if for client D the sum of stock column is 2 it should count as only one client.

Also I need to acumulated (the amount of active clients)  when i filter by a Table Dates (column: year-month).

```
            Client  DATE        Category    product     stock
            A       30-ene-20   Category1   1001        1
            A       8-may-20    Category1   1001        -1
            A       10-sep-20   Category1   1002        1
            A       1-nov-20    Category1   1002        -1
            A       8-nov-20    Category1   1003        1
            A       8-may-21    Category1   1003        -1
            A       11-jun-21   Category1   1004        1
            A       8-nov-21    Category1   1004        -1
            A       11-dic-21   Category1   1005        1
            B       30-ene-20   Category2   3001        1
            B       15-mar-20   Category2   3001        -1
            B       30-jul-20   Category2   3002        1
            B       30-jul-20   Category2   3002        -1
            C       7-feb-20    Category3   2001        1
            C       7-ago-20    Category3   2001        -1
            C       7-feb-21    Category3   2002        1
            C       16-abr-21   Category3   2002        -1
            C       7-ago-21    Category3   2003        1
            C       7-feb-22    Category3   2003        -1
            C       15-abr-22   Category3   2004        1
            D       30-jul-20   Category1   4001        1
            D       30-ene-21   Category1   4001        -1
            D       30-jul-21   Category1   4002        1
            D       3-nov-21    Category1   4002        -1
            D       3-nov-21    Category1   4003        1
            D       2-may-22    Category1   4004        1
            D       3-may-22    Category1   4005        1
```

I need this results:

```
            Category    Clients
            Category1   2
            Category2   0
            Category3   1
            Total       3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Used 3 measures -

```
1. count_cust = DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Client])
2. sum_stock = if(sum(Sheet1[stock]) > 0, 1, 0)
3. cust_cntxsum_stock = [count_cust]*Sheet1[sum_stock]
```

Multiplied, measure 1 and 2, to get desired counts.

Visual with field: category and measure: cust_cntxsum_stock as needed output -

[image]

Visual to show all measures -

[image]

Adding below for correcting Totals -

```
Measure1 = sum(Sheet1[stock])
Measure2 = calculate(if(Sheet1[Measure1]>0, DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Client]),0) )
Measure2_adj = IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(Sheet1[Category]))=1,[Measure2],SUMX(VALUES(Sheet1[Category]),[Measure2])
```

Desired output -

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. In this case the total has to be 3, not 4 Because is the sum of active clients

Comment: Yeah, missed that. For measures power BI will do total including the formula, so we need to somehow make power BI avoid doing that. It can done either using new columns rather then measure, but then column calculations are per row or we can add another sub-measure to get us value of rows for our main measure. I have put another measure and modified output to solution. Hope it helps. Also for work-around you can refer - https://archerpoint.com/how-to-make-measures-total-correctly-in-power-bi-tables/

Comment: Thanks again for you answer, but in this case I found one mistake in the total. 
 I use a table Dates to filter ("year-month") the main table and when i selected the column "year-month": "2020-05", the total is 1 and Category1 is 0. A similar example is in "2020-08"

Comment: I use this table: 

TableDates = ADDCOLUMNS ( CALENDAR (FIRSTDATE(Sheet1[DATE]), TODAY()), "year", YEAR ( [Date] ), "MonthNumber", FORMAT ( [Date], "MM" ), "year-month", FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYY-MM" ), "month-year", FORMAT ( [Date], "MM-'YY" ) )